# Diferencias y usos de `PartialEq` y `Eq`

Tags: rust

Rust tiene una particularidad que permite ramificar la forma de comparar objetos a través de los *traits* `PartialEq` y `Eq`.

Deduciendo de la documentación, la única diferencia entre ambos sería que `Eq` adiciona a la fórmula la propiedad reflexiva.

Pero entonces ¿existen casos de objetos que implementen `PartialEq` con código personalizado y que requieran de `Eq`?

Es decir, si creando mi propia implementación de `PartialEq` para comparar ambos objetos ¿en que caso sería aconsejable e incluso obligatorio usar `Eq`?

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Category {
    Hatchback,
    Truck,
}

struct Car {
    color: Color,
    category: Category,
}

impl PartialEq for Car {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.category == other.category
    }
}


fn main() {
    let my_hatch = Car {
        color: Color::Blue,
        category: Category::Hatchback,
    };
    
    let my_truck = Car {
        color: Color::Red,
        category: Category::Truck,
    };
    
    println!("Are those two cars equals? {}", my_hatch == my_truck);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es tal y como tu lo has descrito, `PartialEq` y `Eq` solo se diferencian en la propiedad **reflexiva** (es decir, `Siendo T: PartialEq, T == T no se cumple necesariamente`). Esto se ve fácil con el siguiente enum:

```rust
enum Error {
    BadRequest { code: u32 },
    ConnectionFailed { code: u32 },
    UnknownError,
}
```

En este caso dos errores del tipo `Error::BadRequest { code }` se podrán comparar a la perfección y serán iguales a sí mismos si el código y la variante es igual, pero `Error::UnknownError` no, ya que dos errores de ese tipo no sabes si son iguales ya que como su origen es desconocido no puedes afirmar que sean del mismo tipo entre ellos aún si estructuralmente son iguales para el ordenador.

Otro ejemplo es `f32`, que es el propio ejemplo que te dan en la documentación, todos los números son comparables entre sí, menos `Nan` que es resultado de `0/0` por ejemplo, o raíz de un numero negativo, pero en ningun caso puedes decir que son el mismo numero ya que `sqrt(-1) == sqrt(-2)` es falso, que en rust se representaría para el compilador así `NaN == NaN` y `NaN` estructuralmente es igual pero lógicamente es distinto.

En tu ejemplo al no existir ambiguedades **lo lógico** (pero no necesario si no usas la propiedad reflexiva) es añadir también el `Eq`, pero tampoco es algo para preocuparse demasiado, mucha gente añade siempre los dos a no ser que encuentre algún problema lógico al hacerlo.